# Как получить путь к файлу через ярлык?

Tags: c#, файлы

Добрый вечер!

Возник следующий вопрос: как, имея ярлык (к примеру, на рабочем столе), получить путь к файлу, на который он ссылается, средствами C#?

Comment: Ну, для начала, ярлык есть ссылка на объект в пространстве имён Windows Shell, поэтому он вовсе не обязательно ссылается на файл.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!тВопрос закрыт, разобрался, сделал по второму варианту, отдельное спасибо за спецификацию, подчерпнул из нее много нового!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Здесь](http://blez.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/get-file-shortcuts-target-with-c/) есть довольно большой пример, [здесь](https://code.google.com/p/8bits/downloads/detail?name=The_Windows_Shortcut_File_Format.pdf) валяется спека, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565885/net-read-binary-contents-of-lnk-file) пример поменьше.